# cordova.plugims undefined on deviceready

Tags: cordova

I have added the "*de.appplant.cordova.plugin.emailcomposer.EmailComposer*" plugin inside my Cordova app. I am simply trying to access `cordova.plugins in my`deviceready`to check if the plugin is installed properly`. However, getting `Cordova undefined`. Also, tried using `window.plugin`; that too turns out to be `undefined`. What am I missing here?

I have added the plugin through command line and have the following code in my `config.xml`:

```
<feature name="EmailComposer">
      <param name="android-package" value="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.emailcomposer.EmailComposer" />
</feature>
```

This is how my html file looks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <title>email</title>

<script>

    function emailtest(){
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
            alert(cordova.plugins);
            alert(window.plugin);
        }, false);
    }

</script>

</head>
<body >
<input type="button" onclick="emailtest()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <title>email</title>

<script>

    function emailtest(){
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
            alert(cordova.plugins);
            alert(window.plugin);
        }, false);
    }

</script>

This is what my html looks like:

</head>
<body >
<input type="button" onclick="emailtest()">
</body>
</html>

Comment: Put the code in your post, not here I can't read it.

Comment: From what I see your code has errors. Please put your code in the post.

Comment: added code in summary itself

Answer (score 0):

@avi,
your page had lots of errors. I have cleaned it up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>email</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script>
    var readyForEmailTest = false
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
        alert(cordova.plugins);
        alert(window.plugin);
        readyForEmailTest = true;
    }, false);

</script>
</head>
<body >
<!-- (...) -->
</body>
</html>
```

- W3 directives are not needed in the webpage. No one will read the inside of the page, except you. This means no server will read your webpage.
- It is not good practice to load *assets* (JS files, images, etc) from remote websites. Have the assests on the device.
- You forgot the `cordova.js` file. It needs to be listed for things to work. I forget if the compiler adds the file.
- You need to wait for the `deviceready` event to fire before you do ANYTHING.

The following links will help you.

- [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

**Tutorial on Boilerplates**
The bare minimum you need.

- [Three (3) Phonegap Build Boilerplates for For Android and iOS](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/blog/2015/BLOG.2015-06-19.codesnippets.html)